# receiving image by path

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to dynamically grab images saved in assets / imgs by the path in the database.
But instead of receiving the image, I'm getting only its name, named by id-1 / id-2. . .
What am I doing wrong? Could someone please help me? I need to receive the images according to each product, but I can not.
I will be very grateful to anyone who can help me. Thanks!

If you do not know how to help me in this topic, tell me how I can dynamically search for images. I have a list of edited products in the database, I just can not bring the image.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Duuu.png)

my DB

```
`getProdutosCategoria(pcategoria: number){

return new Promise<Produto[]>((resolve, reject) => { 

  let sql = "SELECT PR.NOM_PRODUTO, SC.NOM_SUBCATEGORIA, PR.DESC_PRODUTO, PR.VAL_PRODUTO, PR.DESC_DESCONTO, PR.DESC_EXPERIENCIA, 'assets/imgs/id-'|| cast(PR.ID as VARCHAR(100)) AS nom_imagem " + 
            "FROM TB_PRODUTO PR " +
            "     INNER JOIN TB_SUBCATEGORIA SC " +
            "        ON SC.ID = PR.SUBCATEGORIA_ID " +
            "WHERE SC.CATEGORIA_ID = " + pcategoria;
  console.log(sql);          
  this.executeQuery(sql).then(data => {
    let products = [];
    data.forEach(function (row) {
      let product: Produto = { nom_produto: row[0], nom_subcategoria: row[1],desc_produto: row[2],val_produto: row[3], desc_desconto: row[4], desc_experiencia: row[5],  nom_imagem: row[6]}
      products.push(product);
    });
    resolve(products);

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

});
```

}`

```
   Modal
export interface Produto {
nom_produto: string;
nom_subcategoria: string;
desc_produto: string;
val_produto: number;
desc_desconto: string;
desc_experiencia: string;
nom_imagem: string;
}
```

and my HTML

```
<img src="img/{{produto.nom_imagem}}" class="imgast">
```

Comment: How does your `ng-repeat` look like?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu  i not using ng-repeat. How can i use? can you help me?